# How to test react router routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to test the routes from App, the tests are returning ok, but something seems wrong. It doesn't test the routes, I think it only tests if is getting the components. Also, I have problems in testing the NotFound page component.. if I put a test case like others from above, it always receives 0.

I tried to test the routes with MemoryRouter wrapper using initialEntries, but I'm not sure it does work properly.

// App file

```
const App: React.FC = observer(() => (
  <StoreContext.Provider value={new Store()}>
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={CampList} />
          <Route path="/camp/active" component={CampList} />
          <Route path="/camp/inactive" component={CampList} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </StoreContext.Provider>
```

// test file

```
 describe('routes using memory router', () => {
   it('should show CampList component for \'/camp/active\' 
 route', () => {
     const component = mount(
       <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/camp/active']}>
         <App />
       </MemoryRouter>,
     );
     expect(component.find(CampList)).toHaveLength(1);
   })

   it('should show CampList component for \'/camp/inactive\' 
 route', () => {
     const component = mount(
       <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/camp/inactive']}>
         <App />
       </MemoryRouter>,
     );
     expect(component.find(CampList)).toHaveLength(1);
   })
```

I would like to test if the route given will return the expected component.